# This vb net code doesn't connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've written this code in VB.Net.

```
Public Class DBConf
    Public connectionstring As String
    Public mysqlconnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)

Private Sub ButtonConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonConnect.Click

        connectionstring = "datasource=" & TextBox1.Text & ";port=" & TextBox2.Text & ";username=" & TextBox3.Text & ";password=" & TextBox4.Text


        Try

            mysqlconnection.Open()
            MsgBox("Connesso!", MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            'MsgBox("Connessione non riuscita. Verificare i dati immessi e riprovare.", MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try
```

where the textboxes represent user inputs.
It doesn't connect to my MySQL Server.
However, if I put my string instead of the variable "connectionstring" in `Public mysqlconnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionstring)`, it connects.
What is here wrong?
Thanks to all.

Comment: You're not assigning the connectionstring into your connection in the button click. That aside, you should have a serious look at how and where you open and close connections etc. Get them all inside a common method and in a `Using` block to prevent later pain.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I forgot to close the connection but it was just a test. You solved my problem!

Comment: the mysqlconnection object should be defined in a using statement inside the click method...also no reason for either of those variables to be at the class level